# How can I change users in during my bash script excecution and continue running commands with the new user?

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

So I'm making an ubuntu bash script for an installation and in the middle of it I have to change users to the postgres user (running `sudo su postgres`) then I have to enter postgres shell and run some commands more.
The problem is that when I change user to the postgres user the commands keeps running with the root user. How can I run these commands with the postgres user?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo -u postgres command`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `sudo su user` you switch to this users shell, but your script is still in your first root shell, and is waiting for `sudo su user` to finish so it can continue.

You should run each command for another user like this:
`sudo -u other_user your_command`